# Wildcard and automatic subdomains

Tags: wildcard

I was browsing the internet and I do not know what's going on anymore.

I have a vps with Centos webpanel, on vps is a script that is supposed to automatically create subdomains for users who want to add their business card.

Domain in OVH, I added in the dns zone entry: * .mysite.eu A IP vps.

File /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts.conf

```
ServerName myserver
ServerAlias *.mysite.eu
ServerAlias www.mysite.eu
ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.eu
DocumentRoot /home/lupus/public_html
UseCanonicalName Off
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/lupus/public_html/cgi-bin/

# Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/lupus/mysite.eu/*.conf

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
    UserDir enabled lupus
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup lupus lupus
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup lupus lupus
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/lupus
</IfModule>

<Directory "/home/lupus/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

When trying to create a business card, the address is: https: //mysite.eu/company/%26nbsp%3B (after these strange characters, I can enter the name of the company)

And it should be: https: //company/mysite.eu

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have already sent a feature request to CWP team for this feature.

Anyhow, for the time being now, you can create wildcard subdomain through this code. Paste this code at the end of /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts.conf file through SSH or file manager

```
# vhost_start *.yourdomain.com
ServerName _wildcard_.yourdomain.com
ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com
ServerAdmin hostinpk@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/home/yourdoma/public_html"
ErrorLog "/home/yourdoma/public_html/error.log"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/yourdoma/public_html/cgi-bin/
# Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/yourdoma/*.yourdomain.com/*.conf
SuexecUserGroup yourdoma yourdoma
suPHP_UserGroup yourdoma yourdoma
 &lt;Directory "/home/yourdoma/public_html"&gt;
 AllowOverride All
# vhost_end *.yourdomain.com
```

Don't forget to replace **yourdomain.com** with your own domain name and **yourdoma** with the user name of the account.

Save the file and start using wildcard subdomains on your account.